# What certifications must one have to repair/alter propellers and instruments?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance, pilot-certification

According to [14 CFR 65 Subpart D](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr;sid=4128757e254de87854acaaa4090010b9;rgn=div5;view=text;node=14%3A2.0.1.1.4;idno=14;cc=ecfr#sp14.2.65.d)

> A certificated mechanic may perform or supervise the maintenance, preventive maintenance or alteration of an aircraft or appliance, or a part thereof, for which he is rated (**but excluding major repairs to, and major alterations of, propellers, and any repair to, or alteration of, instruments**), and may perform additional duties in accordance with §§65.85, 65.87, and 65.95.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

What certifications are necessary to affect the repairs or alterations specifically excluded from a "mechanic" certificate?

Comment: I suspect a Full A&P rating is needed, with a further rating to work on instruments - not that much could be done outside of send an instrument back to the OEM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to be an [FAA Certified Repair Station](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/repair/) approved to work on instrumentation, propellors etc. [as noted here](http://nata.aero/data/files/part145_4x9.pdf)

> The FAA lists and approves ratings on a form called operations
>   specifications. The operating specifications will also be displayed in
>   the maintenance facility, usually right next to the certificate. Like
>   other businesses, most maintenance facilities advertise on the Web and
>   in trade magazines, so you have many ways to research what rating a
>   particular repair station may have. There are basically six ratings
>   that pertain to a repair station:
>
> •  Airframe
>
> •  Powerplant
>
> •  Propeller
>
> •  Radio
>
> •  Instrument
>
> • Accessory

To be an approved Repair Station the employees must conform to

> ***§ 145.157 Personnel authorized to approve an article for return to
>   service.***
>
> (a) A certificated repair station located inside the United States
>   must ensure each person authorized to approve an article for return to
>   service under the repair station certificate and operations
>   specifications is certificated under part 65. (b) A certificated
>   repair station located outside the United States must ensure each
>   person authorized to approve an article for return to service under
>   the repair station certificate and operations specifications is—
>
> (1) Trained in or has 18 months practical experience with the methods,
>   techniques, practices, aids, equipment, and tools used to perform the
>   maintenance, preventive maintenance, or alterations; and
>
> (2) Thoroughly familiar with the applicable regulations in this
>   chapter and proficient in the use of the various inspection methods,
>   techniques, practices, aids, equipment, and tools appropriate for the
>   work being performed and approved for return to service. (c) A
>   certificated repair station must ensure each person authorized to
>   approve an article for return to service understands, reads, and
>   writes English.

They also must meet the requirements set fourth in:

> (b) Meets the eligibility requirements of [§65.101](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/65.101).

[which you can find here.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/65.101)

You can find the full regulations pertinent to becoming a [repair station here](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2011-title14-vol3/pdf/CFR-2011-title14-vol3-part145.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Do some more reading at the link you provided in these paragraphs. I think that will answer your question.

§65.80   Certificated aviation maintenance technician school students.

§65.81   General privileges and limitations.

§65.83   Recent experience requirements.

§65.85   Airframe rating; additional privileges.

§65.87   Powerplant rating; additional privileges.

§65.89   Display of certificate.

§65.91   Inspection authorization.

§65.92   Inspection authorization: Duration.

§65.93   Inspection authorization: Renewal.

§65.95   Inspection authorization: Privileges and limitations.

> A certificated mechanic with an airframe rating can approve and return to service an airframe, or any related part or appliance, of an aircraft with a special airworthiness certificate in the light-sport category after performing and inspecting a major repair or major alteration for products that are not produced under an FAA approval provided the work was performed in accordance with instructions developed by the manufacturer or a person acceptable to the FAA.
>
> A certificated mechanic with a powerplant rating can approve and return to service a powerplant or propeller, or any related part or appliance, of an aircraft with a special airworthiness certificate in the light-sport category after performing and inspecting a major repair or major alteration for products that are not produced under an FAA approval, provided the work was performed in accordance with instructions developed by the manufacturer or a person acceptable to the FAA.

and further past the A&P ratings above is IA:

> The holder of an inspection authorization may—
>
> (1) Inspect and approve for return to service any aircraft or related part or appliance (except any aircraft maintained in accordance with a continuous airworthiness program under part 121 of this chapter) after a major repair or major alteration to it in accordance with part 43 [New] of this chapter, if the work was done in accordance with technical data approved by the Administrator; and
>
> (2) Perform an annual, or perform or supervise a progressive inspection according to §§43.13 and 43.15 of this chapter.